# Creating index in SQL Server with ONLINE = ON if supported

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating an index in a SQL Server table with `ONLINE = ON` option:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Name ON Users (Name) WITH ONLINE = ON
```

If this script is run on non-Enterprise SQL Server edition I get this error:

> Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server.

How to write a SQL script to use `ONLINE = ON` option on Enterprise editions and not to use it for non-supported editions?

Comment: check select SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') is enterprise and IF.

Comment: It still shows the same error even if ONLINE = ON inside 'if' with non-satisfied condition.

Comment: @alexey try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407490/how-to-create-nonclustered-index-with-online-if-available

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help

```
IF  SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') like '%Enterprise%Edition%'
BEGIN
CREATE INDEX IX_Name ON Users (Name) WITH ONLINE = ON
END
```

Also I think the `login` you are using should have *permission* to `View Server State`

Comment: Edition should be Enterprise or Developer.

Comment: Another option: SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 3 /* Enterprise, Developer */ OR SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 5 /* SQL Azure */.

Comment: If you run this script against SQL Express it still drops 'Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server.'